# Ubuntu 14.04 unity broken no launchbar menu bar

Tags: unity, nvidia, xorg

I tried installing nvidia 331.79 driver from xorg-edger ppa, but after installation the unity is broken that no launchbar and no menu bar. The login screen worked properly but right after I logged in I could not do anything (no launchbar but right-click on desktop was working), even Ctrl+Alt+T failed to trigger a terminal session.

I pressed Ctrl+Alt+F1 switching to command console to login (no GUI).
I restored to official repository nvidia 331.38 driver but the same problem (no launchbar) still persisted after login. I also tried the command `unity --replace` but it did not help.

By googling the error message of `unity --replace` I came to a knowledge page of "Parallels" shown below. I have no Parallels installed but the page just described exactly same error message and syndrome (no launchbar), so I followed its instructions and it JUST WORKED (restoring my launchbar and menu bar)!

http://kb.parallels.com/121300

These are the main commands I ran following the page's instructions, where "XXXXXXXX" is the backup timestamp of my xorg.conf file.

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf.XXXXXXXX /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf
export DISPLAY=:0
gsettings reset org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ active-plugins
```

I know the first line was moving a backup file, could anyone explain the purpose of other two lines and why they helped me to resolve the issue?
Afterward I checked the folder `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` but I did not find the file `xorg.conf` which was supposed I moved there by the first command.

I want to know why it helped me, and why the `xorg.conf` file was not found afterward.

Many Thanks!

Comment: What is your setup? Are you dual-booting with another OS or running Ubuntu in a VM?

Comment: Yes, it is dual boot with Win7 but I seldom use Win7 (only two times in 2014), not using VM.  

As stated above, the issue happened after I install the xorg-edger ppa (maybe incompatibility issue), although I then un-install (ppa-purge) the ppa it did not help resolving the problem.  

I ended up in the knowledge page of "Parallels" just because the page described exactly the same syndrome and error message, so it was showed up within the first few results in my google search.

Comment: Are you running Bumblebee on a machine with hybrid graphics? ie Do you have two graphics cards? I had a similar issue where my desktop would not load (just the background and pointer), but it was resolved by `ppa-purge xorg-edgers`. Strange how this fixes it - does it fix your Bumblebee setup as well?